# How can I display a subpage of my Silverstripe website as a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain, silverstripe

I have a website build on Silverstripe 3.

Now I want that a user can enter the Subdomain URL info.mydomain.com and see the content of the page mydomain.com/subpage-url/. But without redirection. The subdomain URL should stay in their browser.

I already created the subdomain and let it point to the root directory of my website. As I understand it right I now need some rewrite conditions in my .htaccess file? And that is the point I struggle with. I googled a little bit and did some trail and fail but nothing seems to work. Maybe I understand it totally wrong, used the wrong rewrite conditions or insert them on the wrong place.. Maybe there are Silverstripe specific issues to pay attention to?

Long story short: I need help please!

Comment: You could do this with custom htaccess rules - you could also use the "subsites" module, although that will give you a separate SiteTree for your subsites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robbie Averill pointed out in his comment, you could install the [Subsites](https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/subsites) module. But you'd have to create a Subsite (eg. a separate site-tree) for every domain.

There's another module though, the [homepagefordomain](https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/homepagefordomain) module. With that module you can specify one (or multiple) domains per page. When you visit one of these domains, the page that was specified as home-page for that domain will show up. I think this is a more flexible approach than messing with the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you very much! The plugin homepagefordomain works perfectly! :)